# Vue3 and leaflet implementation, problem with the render first time

Tags: leaflet, vuejs3

I am using Leaflet in a vue3 application with a single file component. Problem experimented is, map is rendered correctly except icons and props value in the legend the first time or after refresh. If I do light scroll appears correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code of the component

```
    <script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, ref, toRefs } from 'vue'
import L, { map, Map } from 'leaflet'
import 'leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.css'
import 'leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css'
import type { Coordinates } from '@/models/ui/Coordinates'
import { RouteNamespace } from '@/models/common/domain/RouteNameSpace'
import { i18n } from '@/common/i18n'

const props = defineProps<Coordinates>()
const { coords, available, unavailable } = toRefs(props)
const mapElement = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)
let leafletMap: Map | undefined

const getStatus = () => 'rgba(234,40,57,0.76)' //TODO REMOVE HARDCODED VALUE, IT SHOULD BE ACTIVE PROP

const colorMarker = () => {
  const svgIcon = `
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" height="24px">
        <path d="M12,2.01C8.14,2.01,5.01,5.15,5.01,9c0,3.957,4.395,10.373,6.215,12.631c0.4,0.496,1.151,0.496,1.55,0 C14.595,19.373,18.99,12.957,18.99,9C18.99,5.15,15.86,2.01,12,2.01z M11,17v-5H9l4-7v5h2L11,17z"
              fill="${getStatus()}" stroke="${getStatus()}" stroke-width="0"/>
    </svg>
  `
  return L.divIcon({
    className: 'marker',
    html: svgIcon,
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [12.5, 41],
    popupAnchor: [0, -36]
  })
}

const createLegendRow = (color: string, label: string) => `
  <div class="w-auto h-auto p-3 bg-white border-round opacity-80">
    <a href="" class="text-gray-700">
      <div class="flex flex-row">
        <i class="status" style="background-color: ${color}"></i>
        <span class="font-bold ml-2">${label}</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
`
const initMap = (element: HTMLElement) => {
  const map = L.map(element).setView([41, 0], 5)
  leafletMap = map

  L.tileLayer(import.meta.env.VITE_OPENSTREETMAP, {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
  }).addTo(map)

  const legend = L.control({
    position: 'bottomright'
  })

  const div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'legend')
  const color = ['green', 'red']
  const label = [
    `${available.value} ${i18n.global.t('status.available')}`,
    `${unavailable.value} ${i18n.global.t('status.unavailable')}`
  ]
  legend.onAdd = () => {
    const rows = color.map((item, index) => createLegendRow(item, label[index]))
    div.innerHTML = rows.join('')
    return div
  }
  legend.addTo(map)
  coords.value.forEach((crd) => {
    const [id, popupContent, active, latitude, longitude] = crd
    const marker = L.marker([latitude, longitude], { icon: colorMarker() }).bindPopup(
      `<a href="${RouteNamespace.locations}/${id}">
        <div>
          <h6>${popupContent}</h6>
          <div class="flex">
            <div class="status status__available mr-2"></div>
            <span>Disponible</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>`
    )
    marker.addTo(map)
  })

  return map
}

const removeMap = () => {
  if (leafletMap) {
    leafletMap.off()
    leafletMap.remove()
    leafletMap = undefined
  }
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  (entries) => {
    if (entries[0].isIntersecting && mapElement.value) {
      removeMap()
      leafletMap = initMap(mapElement.value)
    }
  },
  { threshold: [1] }
)

onMounted(() => {
  if (mapElement.value) {
    observer.observe(mapElement.value)
  } else {
    console.error('error')
  }
})
</script>
<template>
  <div id="map" ref="mapElement" />
</template>
<style scoped lang="scss">
#map {
  height: 60vh;
}
</style>
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a number of reasons why this is happening. It could be a race condition with `IntersectionObserver`, it could be the prop values changing due to a parent update, it could be CSS on render, or a combination.

You could try working around using an `IntersectionObserver` to determine when to initialize the map and use Vue's `nextTick` to ensure the map initializes after the component and any children fully render.

**Example 1**:

```
import { nextTick } from 'vue';

onMounted(async () => {
   await nextTick();
   if (mapElement.value) {
      removeMap();
      leafletMap = initMap(mapElement.value);
   } else {
      console.error('error');
   }
});
```

You could also watch for prop changes. If the prop values can change and you want to update the legend accordingly, consider using `watch` to react to these changes.

**Example 2**:

```
import { watch } from 'vue';

watch([available, unavailable], () => {
   // Code to update the legend when the prop values change
}, { deep: true });
```

Another thing to look at might be the way Leaflet calculates size during initialization. If the div `mapElement` isn't visible or doesn't have a set size, this can cause some issues. To work around this, you can utilize Leaflet's `invalidateSize()`

**Example**:

```
if (leafletMap) {
   leafletMap.invalidateSize();
}
```

This will force Leaflet to recalculate the size of the map container.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much Matthew. You saved my week!! Example 2 works!!